# .NET Core build rebuilding projects that have not changed

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I have some C# and F# projects that were migrated from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET Core 2.0. After modifying one source file and building in VS 2017 it keeps rebuilding several (sometimes all) projects every time I select "Build Solution" without further changes. I can see this from the final line of the output:

```
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 11 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Building from the command line with `dotnet build` also take a long time, though I can't be sure that it's rebuilding, because it doesn't output a count of how many projects were rebuilt, like VS does.

How do I troubleshoot why unchanged projects are being rebuilt?

Comment: @R. Richards: Why waste extra time for no reason?

Comment: Did you ever find any solutions to this?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me now, but I don't remember when or how it stopped - it's been too long.

Answer (score 1):

There are still a few bugs with the "up-to-date" check in visual studio, especially if there are items marked as "copy to output directory" in subfolders.

The projects aren't actually recompiled, but an MSBuild-"build" is triggered that will check for all inputs (and then do nothing). For the "up-to-date" projects, VS skips invoking MSBuild completely which makes it faster.

You can check for similar issues or report new issues for the up-to-date check at https://github.com/dotnet/project-system